# $N$ square-free $\Rightarrow \exists a \in (\mathbb Z / N\mathbb Z)^{\times}, (\frac{a}{N}) = -1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, legendre-symbol, jacobi-symbol

I want to show that if $N$ is a square free odd integer then there is some number coprime to $N$ such that the Jacobi Symbol $(\frac{a}{N}) = -1 $

Honestly I don't even know how to start showing this.

I know that for every odd prime $p$ there are $\frac{p-1}{2}$ quadratic residues$\pmod p$.

Taking the factorisation $N = p_1\dots p_k$ of distinct primes then, maybe I could argue that there's something that isn't a quadratic residue to an odd number of the prime factors. However, I can't quite see how I might manage something like that.

Comment: Chinese remainder theorem?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: choose $a$ so that
$$
\begin{align*}
a&\equiv1\pmod{p_1}\\
a&\equiv1\pmod{p_2}\\
&\cdots\\
a&\equiv1\pmod{p_{k-1}}\\
a&\equiv b\pmod{p_k}
\end{align*}
$$
where $b$ is not a square modulo $p_k$.